# How to set duration of the transcoded output file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-elastic-transcoder

What is the correct way to specify 'duration' of the transcoded output in Amazon Elastic Transcoder? For example no matter how long the input video file, I would like to have a maximum of 3 minutes output.

I'm using a `node.js` `lambda` to kick off transcoder jobs. Looking at [AWS.ElasticTranscoder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticTranscoder.html#createJob-property), however, unable to determine a 'duration' parameter.

`SegmentDuration` seems similar but it appears to apply only to `MPEG`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the TimeSpan map that is part of the Input parameters:

```
Input: {
    AspectRatio: 'STRING_VALUE',
    Container: 'STRING_VALUE',
    DetectedProperties: {
      DurationMillis: 0,
      FileSize: 0,
      FrameRate: 'STRING_VALUE',
      Height: 0,
      Width: 0
    },
<snip>
    Interlaced: 'STRING_VALUE',
    Key: 'STRING_VALUE',
    Resolution: 'STRING_VALUE',
    TimeSpan: {
      Duration: 'STRING_VALUE',
      StartTime: 'STRING_VALUE'
    }
```

> TimeSpan — (map) Settings for clipping an input. Each input can have
>   different clip settings.
>
> StartTime — (String) The place in the input file where you want a clip
>   to start. The format can be either HH:mm:ss.SSS (maximum value:
>   23:59:59.999; SSS is thousandths of a second) or sssss.SSS (maximum
>   value: 86399.999). If you don't specify a value, Elastic Transcoder
>   starts at the beginning of the input file.
>
> Duration — (String) The duration of the clip. The format can be either
>   HH:mm:ss.SSS (maximum value: 23:59:59.999; SSS is thousandths of a
>   second) or sssss.SSS (maximum value: 86399.999). If you don't specify
>   a value, Elastic Transcoder creates an output file from StartTime to
>   the end of the file.
>
> If you specify a value longer than the duration of the input file,
>   Elastic Transcoder transcodes the file and returns a warning message.